# How to POST with request in Express

Tags: node.js, express, npm, http-post, httprequest

So I'm trying to POST a new user to Intercom using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module, but can't seem to get the format correct. I'm able to do GET requests just fine with request and POST with the same data with CURL. So my conclusion is there must be somthing wrong with the way I'm using the request library.

Working CURL request:

```
    curl https://api.intercom.io/users \
-X POST \
-u xxx:da39xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0709 \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  "user_id": "25",
  "email": "wash@serenity.io",
  "name": "Hoban Washburne",
  "signed_up_at": 1392731331,
  "last_seen_ip" : "1.2.3.4"
}
```

Not working server side request:

```
  request.post('https://api.intercom.io/users',
  {
    'auth': {
      'user': 'xxx',
      'pass': 'xxx',
      'sendImmediately': false
    }},
      {
        "user_id": "193",
          "email": "test@test.io",
          "name": "Hoban Washburne",
          "signed_up_at": 1392731331,
          "last_seen_ip" : "1.2.3.4",
      },function (error, response, body) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info);
    console.log(error);
  });
res.status(200).send(info);
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You...might want to revoke that API key...

Comment: That's just the example API key from the docs. @slugonamission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the format of the request based on [this blog post](http://blog.modulus.io/node.js-tutorial-how-to-use-request-module)

Here's an answer that worked for me.

```
request({
    'url': 'https://api.intercom.io/users', //URL to hit
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    'auth': {
      'user': 'xxxxxx', //org ID
      'pass': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', //API key
      'sendImmediately': false
    },

    //Lets post the following key/values as form
    'json': {
      "user_id": "193",
        "email": "test@test.io",
        "name": "Hoban Washburne",
        "signed_up_at": 1392731331,
        "last_seen_ip" : "1.2.3.4"
    }
}, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusCode, body);
    }
    res.status(200).send("this is a test");
});
```